Question about partition of $\mathbb{H}$
Let $$T= \{ z \in \mathbb{H} : -1 \le \Re(z) < 1\}$$ and $$S = \{z \in \mathbb{H} : |z + \frac{1}{2}| > \frac{1}{2}, \, |z - \frac{1}{2}| \ge \frac{1}{2}\},$$
where $\mathbb{H}$ denotes the upper half-plane.
We define functions $j(z) = \frac{-1}{z}$, $\sigma(z) = \frac{z}{-2z+1}$ and $\tau(z) = z + 2$.

Lemma:  The following statements are true: 
$(i)$ the sets $\tau^n(T) \, (n \in \mathbb{Z})$ are disjoint, and their union is $\mathbb{H}$. 
$(ii)$ the sets $\sigma^n(S) \, (n \in \mathbb{Z})$ are disjoint, and their union is $\mathbb{H}$.

In the proof, the author says that these statements are obvious from the next figures:

Ok. For $(i)$ is easy to see that the function is a translation and the statement is true, from the figure. But mathematically how can I write this?. And $(ii)$ is not obvious for me when I try to look at the figure. How can I proof these? Above is an exercise that says to show that $S = j(T)$ which can be helpful, but again I don't know how to prove it.
Edit: I found that $\tau^n(T) = j(\sigma^n(S))$ and because $j$ is a bijection it preserve partition of $\mathbb{H}$, so $\sigma_n(T)$ is a partition of $\mathbb{H}$
Now, why is $j(S) = T$? Because $j$ is in particular a linear-fractional transformation, $j$ takes lines and circles to lines and circles. And I've tried to get some values of $z$ through $j$ and I got:
$-1 \to 1$, $0 \to \infty$, $1 \to -1$, $1+i \to \frac{i-1}{2}$, $1+2i \to \frac{2i-1}{5}$, $\infty \to 0$, $-1 + i \to \frac{1+i}{2}$, $-1 + 2i \to \frac{1+2i}{5}$, $i \to i$. And if we use the above property of $j$ we get a draw like $S$ (this works because any linear-fractional transformation is in particular a homeomorphism and map boundary to boundary and interior to interior).

What have you tried? Can you write $\tau^n(T)$ in a similar fashion as for $T$ itself?

@BrunoB I've added an edit. Can you tell me if it's ok or not? Thanks!

I think in your edit you swapped $T$ and $S$, but otherwise this seems good to me.

@BrunoB yes. Sorry. It was a typo! Thanks for help!
